# NGINX custom 404 page without redirect

Tags: nginx

By default, when NGINX returns a 404 it renders some default HTML.  For example, something like:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to customize this HTML but leave the URL unchanged.  I've tried setting the error page for 404s:

```
error_page 404 /404.html
```

But this first redirects the browser to `/404.html`.

Is there a way to customize the 404 HTML without redirecting?

Comment: `error_page 404 /404.html;` should not generate a redirect. You can force a redirect by specifying a full URL, but in the form you have in your question, it should not generate a redirect. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I just tried again and it works as expected.  Not sure what config setting I had that was making it redirect to `/404.html`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

may be you can do it as follow by using the `error_page` and `proxy_intercept_errors` directive of nginx

detail config

```
server {
    ## other config
    ## here the proxy_intercept_errors directive is the key
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        ## your 50x.html file parent directory
        root   /var/www; 
    }
    error_page   404  /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        ## your 404.html file parent directory
        root   /var/www; 
    }
}
```

document on nginx official site:

[proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) and [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

Comment: I had missed to set the `proxy_intercept_errors` option and this above saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

This configuration worked for me

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    internal;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal